# preg_match_all and empty keys

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match two regex using a single `preg_match_all` and I need to get 2 arrays containing the matches.

This is my current code:

```
$s = 'abab';
preg_match_all('/(a)|(b)/', $s, $a); 
var_dump($a);
```

It works quite well, if don't consider that the resulting multi-dimensional array is:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
      3 => string 'b' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'b' (length=1)
```

So, I could use `$a[1]` and `$a[2]` but as you can see, these array have empty values on the "not matched" keys.

I'd need:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
      3 => string 'b' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'a' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
```

There is some parameter to pass to `preg_match_all` to get a clean output without empty values? I've already tried `array_filter()` but it doesn't remove them **and I'm looking for a short solution so I can't use the callback of array_filter** (need it for a code-golf challenge).

Comment: This output is exactly what the documentation describes. What does "clean output" mean to you?

Comment: I'm asking an output without empty values (as asked in my question)

Comment: That's because `(a)|(b)` isn't letter-restriction. and all 3 items are correct in result

Comment: added expected output to let you understand what am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea, why do you need it this way, but shortest I have come up with to satisfy your request.

```
$s = 'abab';
preg_match_all('/(a)|(b)/', $s, $a); 
// filter all at once
$a = array_map('array_filter', $a);
var_dump($a);
```